# Decrease regex greed

Tags: regex, greedy

I have the following string:

```
$/Mycollection/Branches/Dev/New/php/MySite/src/MySite/somefolder/src/sad.php
```

I need to create regex pattern and take everything before first appearance of "src".

I've tried to use like that `.+(src)` but as I understood I need to decrease greed, could anyone help ?

Comment: Ungreedy quantifier `?` is applied to quantifier itself, not to "selector": `.+?src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  You can just do this...

```
(^.+?)src
```

Then get the value of the first group captured.

---

You can also do this another way...

```
src.+
```

Then replace the match with `""`.

For example (in C#) ...

```
string value = Regex.Replace(yourstring, "src.+", "");
```

It's actually much more efficient to use this method.  It'll do around 1 million iterations per second vs 150,000 iterations per second for the first method (at least in .NET).  That's partly because there's some overhead in using capturing groups, and partly because of the backtracking that occurs with the lazy `?` quantifier.

By the way, I did the testing and benchmarking with [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) and then [here's a good article that covers the lazy `?` quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: the ^ start of string anchor is not necessary.  "dot" matches *everything*, and this expression will NEVER have to "move up the string" attempting to match at increasing index positions, because "dot" would never have had to give up anything it has already matched.

Comment: @sweaver2112 - The start anchor prevents unnecessary matches.  Without the start anchor, you'd find two matches in this case which of course is completely useless (and slower).

Comment: that's only true when you turn on global matching, which you shouldn't be in this case. Otherwise it makes no difference, matches same either way: http://regexr.com?30b04

Comment: @sweaver2112 - True. Then again, .NET regular expressions have no concept of global matches.  They're global by default.  So this detail would depend on the language used. If it were me, I'd keep the start `^` anchor.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=.%2a?src&input=%24/Mycollection/Branches/Dev/New/php/MySite/src/MySite/somefolder/src/sad.php) regex: `(.*?)src` and use the first captured group only.

Answer (score 0):

In some modern regex implementations, `.+?` is stingy, i e. add a question mark after a greedy quantifier to change it to stingy.